# Spark : put hashmap into Dataset column?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataset `Dataset<Row>` which comes from reading a parquet file. Knowing that one column inside `InfoMap` is of type `Map`.

Now I want to update this column, but when I use `withColumn`, it tells me that I cannot put a hashmap inside because it's not a litteral.

I want to know what is the correct way to update a column of type Map for a dataset ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using typedLit instead of lit

> typedLit
>
> "...The difference between this function and lit() is that this
> function can handle parameterized scala types e.g.: List, Seq and Map"

```
data.withColumn("dictionary", typedLit(Map("foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2)))
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, could you help me with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571242/spark-call-withcolumn-according-to-column-type