# Spark : call withColumn according to column type

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataset that has several types of columns inside : String, Double, List, Map etc.

I want to do a `withColumn` to set some specific values for these columns when the value is null, **depending of the column type**.

I tried something like this :

```
ds.withColumn(colName, when(col(colName).expr().dataType().equals(Datatypes.STRING)), lit("StringDefaultValues"));
```

But it's not working at all. Besides, I cannot find the `Datatypes.MAP` or `Datatypes.LIST` available.

I wonder what is the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
val newData = data.schema.fieldNames.foldLeft(data)((manipulatedData, colName) => {
  manipulatedData.schema(colName).dataType match {
    case IntegerType => manipulatedData.withColumn(colName, when(col(colName).isNull, lit(-1)).otherwise(col(colName)))
    case StringType => manipulatedData.withColumn(colName, when(col(colName).isNull, lit("Empty")).otherwise(col(colName)))
    case MapType(IntegerType, StringType, true) => manipulatedData.withColumn(colName, when(col(colName).isNull, typedLit(Map.empty[Int, String])).otherwise(col(colName)))
    case ArrayType(StringType, true) => manipulatedData.withColumn(colName, when(col(colName).isNull, typedLit(Array.empty[String])).otherwise(col(colName)))
    // TODO: rest of types...
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi it looks promising, do you know how to do this in Java ?

Comment: and do you think withColumn is the best option ? I heard that withColumn is not very good for performance

Comment: It's been years since I last used Java...
Regarding withColumn(), I wouldn't worry about its performance, it's not that bad. Also, you don't have much choice. It's either withColumn(...) or map(...) => Same complexity.

Comment: foldleft will give you very bad performance if you have very huge data.. in this approch you need to write multiple case statements for every map type and array type..

Comment: @Srinivas I think that you're mixing foldLeft with foldRight... 
foldLeft is a "clean" way of invoking a method multiple times and keeping the result each iteration. It has nothing to do with the Dataset it's working on.

Comment: Check this post for performance comparison - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487649/how-can-i-add-multiple-columns-in-spark-datframe-in-efficiently/62487899#62487899

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, To get more control over column data types.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------+---+------+------------------+
|name    |age|salary|options           |
+--------+---+------+------------------+
|Srinivas|1  |1200.0|[name -> srinivas]|
+--------+---+------+------------------+
```

For example I am change `name` and `age` fields to default.

```
scala> 

val columns = df
    .schema
    .map(c => (c.name,c.dataType.typeName))
    .map {
        _ match {
            case (column@"name",datatype@"string") => lit("StringDefaultValues").as(column)
            case (column@"age",datatype@"integer") => lit(30).as(column)
            case (column@"options",datatype@"map") => map(col("name"),col("age")).as(column) // for example
            case (column,datatype) => col(column).as(column)
        }
    }
```

```
scala> df.select(columns:_*).show(false)
+-------------------+---+------+---------------+
|name               |age|salary|options        |
+-------------------+---+------+---------------+
|StringDefaultValues|30 |1200.0|[Srinivas -> 1]|
+-------------------+---+------+---------------+
```

Comment: No I don't have java equivalent .. :)

Comment: This solution enforces the developer to change the code each time the schema changes.

Comment: I agree that ..:)

Comment: Same will apply for your solution also ..:)

Comment: I agree with the benchmark you've presented. But my solution is generic, it can stay the same, regardless. You can cover all data types and it will accommodate to all use-cases.